# jq : update sub-value 1 when sub-value 2 matches a value

Tags: json, bash, jq

I have the following dataset :

```json
{
  "storageSummary": 68624392000000,
  "audit1": {
    "auditScore": 1,
    "suspensionScore": 1,
    "onlineScore": 0.99743587,
    "satelliteName": "us2.storj.io:7777"
  },
  "audit2": {
    "auditScore": 1,
    "suspensionScore": 1,
    "onlineScore": 0.9992917,
    "satelliteName": "saltlake.tardigrade.io:7777"
  },
  "audit3": {
    "auditScore": 1,
    "suspensionScore": 1,
    "onlineScore": 0.99930555,
    "satelliteName": "ap1.storj.io:7777"
  }
}
```

I need (that should be quite simple though...) to update the `auditScore` when `satelliteName` is `us2.storj.io:7777`

EDIT :
I tried the following :
`.[]|select(.satelliteName=="us2.storj.io:7777")` : it only works if I remove the 1st entry in my dataset : `"storageSummary": 68624392000000,`, otherwise, I get `jq: error (at <stdin>:20): Cannot index number with string "satelliteName"`

I tried with map/select/to_entries (I must admit that jq is a bit of wizard to me...), but could not succeed yet. And apparently, I'm not good to define clearly my request to google...

Thanks for your help.

Comment: This was just asked a few days ago, take a look at the existing answers tagged with `jq` or just google it - https://www.google.com/search?q=stackoverflow+jq+modify+based+on+other.

Comment: I understand that you might be bored with newbies always asking for the same thing again and again, and I apologize for that, really. But I did try to search for an existing subject, and could not find any topic that could lead me to my solution. The link you sent me tries to update a value in an array (which is not my case), doing some sort of maths computing on the same value. In my case, I need to update an other sub-value.
I tried "a few" commands on jqplay.org, but non of them did work for now. So I'd appreciate if you (or anyone) could give me a simple solution that could fit my needs

Comment: This forum exists to help people with their code. With no code in your question it's likely to be closed as needing focus or similar. I gave you a way to find code to try for yourself and show in your question so we could help you. Good luck.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use [`with_entries`](https://stedolan.github.io/jq/manual/#to_entries,from_entries,with_entries) to be able to [`select()`](https://stedolan.github.io/jq/manual/#select(boolean_expression)) the object where your condition match.

Then update the `.value.autitScore` to something new:

```
with_entries(select(.value?.satelliteName? == "us2.storj.io:7777").value.auditScore = 999)
```

---

###### [JqPlay Demo](https://jqplay.org/s/byObRV5WfMl)